# .bashrc: line 120: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Tags: linux

when i am deleting empty line 120, it regenerates and that error don't do something but it's annoying me
it's not critical

Can someone help me ?

that's my .bashrc from Ubuntu 22.04 with KDE

if that's information not enough, give me feedback

and sure, i didn't found decision of my problem/error

sorry for my English, I'm not from UK, USA or Australia and I'm only 14 years old ;)

after this, a simply symbols to make that question public

abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGJHKLMNOPQRSTUVYXWZ
adtrfyuhjjjjjdrfxcjhnkmljiuhfdxcfv m,;.'lkjnm ,lkojnm ,lkoj m,;ljknm,k;lpoijk;lpoiujkhm,liouytfgggytrfezsxdcftrzsdxcfgvyt6r5dfxcv jnuiyghjkl;poijkm,;lpojikm,;lioujhkiuy7trdftgrezsdxfrezsdxfcrt5exdfctgrxdfcgvyu7i8ujhklpoijmkl;,ioujhkn,mlioyuhjyutrdfgtrdxcfdrsezdcfrtezsdcftrdfgyhugjhkiojknm,jinm,lpkoijkm,l;pokl;pomkl,;mk;,poijklioyujhy7trfggtr5xdfctrdsedxftrdsezdxftrsexdfrsedcfrsdxftr5dfcgvhygujkioujhkml;jm,;ljmk,k;,jkm,l;jkm

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# colored GCC warnings and errors
#export GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fsudo dpkg
export WINEPREFIX=$HOME/wine32
export WINEARCH=win32
```

Comment: Possibly you have a mistake at the line `fsudo dpkg` - it should be a `fi` there

Comment: `sudo` in `.bashrc` seems like a really bad idea anyway.

Comment: can specify where exactly ?

Comment: you think, if i change line fsudo dpkg it fixes ?

Comment: It should be `fi` followed by `sudo dkpg` on the next line. Looks like a simple editing mistake.

Comment: Your first stop when you get a syntax error should be shellcheck.net, not SO.

Comment: Always first test your script to https://shellcheck.net before asking here. Thanks

Comment: Your first question here, 14 years of age and a non-english speaker. Kudo's to you for soldiering on! (And creating a correctly formatted code sample) ... But learn to post the minimum amount of code that demonstrates your problem. Generally the code, data and error messages (or bad output) will speak for themselves and you shouldn't have to worry about lots of "verbal" explanations. .... All good advice above. Let us know if the added `fi` fixes your problem. Good luck.

Comment: thank you all for your help, i tested my .bashrc on shellchek.net, error was in line 111, it doesn't found fi, I'm asking a question here for the first time, and I'm surprised by the community's hospitality, thanks again to everyone (what I'm must to do after?) and i fix it, yes